# ESXI ftpput fails Syntax problem

Tags: vmware-esxi, busybox

I'm trying to ftpput my virtual machines dirs to our NAS. Which doesn't support NFS. Only FTP and samba.

So I'm in the ESXi console and enter the followin command

ftpput ipaddress /vmfs/volumes/4a1157e1-be81171a-1b39-001d09080124/VMNAME /Backup

/Backup is a public share on the nas, I can access it through any ftp client. After I enter I get the following

ftpput: can't open 'Backup': No such file or directory

I'm kind of in the dark here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage for the ESXi ftpput is

```
Usage: ftpput [options] remote-host remote-file local-file

Store a local file on a remote machine via FTP

Options:
        -v,--verbose    Verbose
        -u,--username   Username
        -p,--password   Password
        -P,--port       Port number
```

ftpput is telling you (correctly) that there is no local /Backup file on the ESXi host. Try switching the /vmfs/volumes/4a1157e1-be81171a-1b39-001d09080124/VMNAME and /Backup parameters around.

e.g.

```
ftpput -u someuser -p somepassword ipaddress /Backup/somefilename /vmfs/volumes/4a1157e1-be81171a-1b39-001d09080124/VMNAME
```

Comment: You were right, I misread the parameters. How stupid.

Thanks Lain